# login form through lightBox Effect

Tags: javascript

I have used a simplest CSS to show a litebox view. The code I used is, I have removed the unnecessary CSS properties from here:

```
<style>
        .black_overlay{
            display: block;

        }
        .white_content {
            display: block;

        }
    </style>
```

Html for the form

```
 <div id="light" class="white_content">      
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />

        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="check(this.form)"/>

        </div>

        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

And a JavaScript function, to check if the fields are correct

```
function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{

var name= $( "#name" );
var pass=$("#password");
 if(name== "admin" && pass == "admin")
  {
  document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
  }
 else
 { 
   alert("Error Password or Username");/*displays error message*/
  }
}
```

The functionality I want is, when the user inputs correct name and pass, that is "admin" the lite box effect fade away... But it is not, the lite box is still there. How can i close it. I also want that this litebox effect should be shown as the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var name= $( "#name" );
var pass=$("#password");
```

with

```
var name= $( "#name" ).val();
var pass=$("#password").val();
```

Comment: I have added the above code, but the same thing happens, the lite box effect is still there. Also ww.php?name=admin&password=admin&submit=Sign+In this appears every time on the adress bar, as i click sign in

Comment: @HanyaIdrees please use .val() as I corrected above. Have you tried?

Comment: @HanyaIdrees could please do your example in http://jsfiddle.net? It's easier for us to see and see the problem.

Comment: Did a correction using jQuery, please check http://jsfiddle.net/ewSHH/1/ Take a look at hide() function from jQuery.

Comment: @axcdnt But, that lite box is still there, after i input "admin" and press sign in.

Comment: I think there was a syntax error. Check this 2nd version http://jsfiddle.net/ewSHH/2/ It hides both elements (fade and light). It looks likes there's a peculiar behavior with browser remembering password. It works often, not always. Kind of stranger.

Comment: @HanyaIdrees please check your console (Firebug or whatever). It's returning some errors with the function. Remove the script tag definition from jsfiddle and it'll work. Give us some feedback!

Comment: @axcdnt I have made it working, I am posting the code as aswer. Thank You So much

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that the submit event is not captured and prevented? In The markup there is no form. If you add it like

```
<form id="submit-me"> your form inputs </div>
```

you can observe it via JS

```
$("#submit-me").submit(function(event) {
  // your js code
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

For your actual example you could try to add a "return false;" in the onclick handler? But I do not know whether this works...

Best regards